# How to modify/re-position GUI element in taskmgr Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, task-manager, gui, desktop-customization

For instance, Windows 7 x64 SP1. Is there any workaround or trick/tip (with resource editing tool, ect...) doing the reposition the number of graph in CPU usage history panel in Performance tab of Windows task manager?

Example: There's a tool to modify hex value of color in performance tab of taskmgr.exe like the picture show below.

[image: 16+8]

But if I want to go further, now my CPU has got 24 threads but it placed in a way that only 16 graphs in one line and remaining 8 grahps in another.

But it looks very unbalance and I just want to reposite/rearrange it to something like 12 + 12 in each line. Is there anyway to do that? (And it's also more logical to display this way because this Dual CPU X5650 is combine 12 threads + 12 threads, not 16+8 like the taskmgr does).

[image: want sth like this]
***This one is what I want (photoshoped the image for illustration only, I haven't manage to pull this off).***

Thanks for reading. And if this question fall into wrong place, feel free to correct it. Hope there's not restriction (software policy?) to ask a question like this here.